# Stripe payment discount for a specific Bank Credit Card

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, discount

I am implementing online payment app with Stripe v6.1.1. 
Every thing works fine, But now I have to implement, giving certain percentage or amount Discount for specific bank credit card when user do transaction with my application.

I go through [Applying  Discounts to Customers](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/discounts), But its doing discounts for all cards for a certain user.

Is anyone know any preferences regarding my doubt? or can anyone guide me to do this?

Thanks

Comment: one way to achieve it, is get the Card Object through stripe api, and if 'brand' field in card object matches your discount card then process the discount on front end itself.

Comment: Sahil, If I want to do a bank wise discount your Idea wont work, because different banks can have same 'brand' for credit cards.(eg: American Express)

Comment: agreed. there is no bank categorization for cards in stripe.

Comment: Sahil, yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Credit Card number contains IIN (issue identification number) [WIKIPEDIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_number)
So, you could use it to prepare a discount. 
All possible ranges you could also ask from your bank.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, lets say if I can get number ranges of all possible credit cards, but to validate that in front end, I do not have access to get user credit card number on Stripe input field, I can get only last 4 number of a card.

Comment: in this case ask directly Striple using help desk.

Comment: Stripe doesn't generally provide the IIN, just the last 4 and the brand as other users pointed out.